# Order by newid() - reader not reading properly

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, reader

I made code that selects a random movie from my table and display stars but for some reason my star aint show probly when im using ORDER by newid()
this is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[select_forside]
AS
   SELECT TOP(1) * 
   FROM [film] 
   INNER JOIN billeder ON film.fk_bil_id = billeder.bill_id 
   ORDER BY newid()

   RETURN 0
```

and my codebehind:

```
SqlConnection conn3 = new SqlConnection();
conn3.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand();
cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd3.CommandText = "select_forside";
cmd3.Connection = conn3;
//  cmd3.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Session["login"];

conn3.Open();

SqlDataReader reader3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

if (reader3.Read())
{
    int stardisplay = Convert.ToInt32(reader3["film_rating"]);

    // display rating
    rating_panel_display.Visible = true;

    // hvis rating = 1
    if (stardisplay == 1)
    {
        star6.Visible = true;
    }

    // hvis rating = 2
    if (stardisplay == 2)
    {
        star6.Visible = true;
        star7.Visible = true;
    }

    // hvis rating = 3
    if (stardisplay == 3)
    {
        star6.Visible = true;
        star7.Visible = true;
        star8.Visible = true;
    }

    // hvis rating = 4
    if (stardisplay == 4)
    {
         star6.Visible = true;
         star7.Visible = true;
         star8.Visible = true;
         star9.Visible = true;
    }

    // hvis rating = 5
    if (stardisplay == 5)
    {
         star6.Visible = true;
         star7.Visible = true;
         star8.Visible = true;
         star9.Visible = true;
         star10.Visible = true;
    }
}

conn3.Close();
```

It works if I say `WHERE film_id = 2` then it will show movie 2 and the correct amount of stars its something about `order by newid()` but I have no idea neither does anyone that I asked

Comment: What if you execute the proc from SSMS, or debug in VS and check what the reader contains. Does the proc return what you expect?

Comment: If you try `SELECT top(10) * FROM [film] INNER JOIN billeder ON film.fk_bil_id = billeder.bill_id ORDER BY newid()` in SSMS does the data returned look right?

Comment: There's no point in `return 0`. Don't return if you have nothing to return :) Is `film_rating` nullable? In that case, `Convert.ToInt32(reader3["film_rating"])` will throw an exception if the value is `NULL`. I'd expect that your "movie 2" has it set properly, but most of the movies don't.

Comment: it returns the right data i made a <p> that gets the value of rating in my repeater its just the reader
could it be bc my Tabel colum film_rating is a Decimal and im not converting it correctly?

Comment: i alrdy made one that display the star with where film = my querystring its just when i use newid() it get confused in the reader

Comment: i ran thisin query
SELECT top(1) * FROM [film] INNER JOIN billeder ON film.fk_bil_id = billeder.bill_id ORDER BY newid()
and it gave the right numbers

Answer (score 0):

a freind told me to remove my repeater and asign the values in the reader and works ty for the help evryone here is the solution

```
 SqlConnection conn3 = new SqlConnection();
        conn3.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd3.CommandText = "select_forside";
        cmd3.Connection = conn3;
       //  cmd3.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Session["login"];

        conn3.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
         // Lav en reader som reader alt ud, billede title og rating
        // og så knyt det til dine forskellige ellementer som Lables og Image
        // Det bliver selvfølgelig et problem hvis du skal have flere end en, for så skal du bruger en repeater
        // og jeg ved ikke hvordan man kan kode bagved til at checke stjerne antallet

        if (reader3.Read())
        {
            int stardisplay = (int)Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(reader3["film_rating"]), 0);

            // display rating
            rating_panel_display.Visible = true;

            forside_img.ImageUrl = "images/plakater/"+ reader3["bill_sti"] +"";
            forside_h2.Text = "" + reader3["film_navn"] + "";
            forside_p.Text = "" + reader3["film_beskr"] + "";
            film_rating.Text = "" + reader3["film_rating"] + "";


            // hvis rating = 1
            if (stardisplay == 1)
            {
                star6.Visible = true;
            }

            // hvis rating = 2
            if (stardisplay == 2)
            {
                star6.Visible = true;
                star7.Visible = true;
            }

            // hvis rating = 3
            if (stardisplay == 3)
            {
                star6.Visible = true;
                star7.Visible = true;
                star8.Visible = true;
            }

            // hvis rating = 4
            if (stardisplay == 4)
            {
                star6.Visible = true;
                star7.Visible = true;
                star8.Visible = true;
                star9.Visible = true;
            }

            // hvis rating = 5
            if (stardisplay == 5)
            {
                star6.Visible = true;
                star7.Visible = true;
                star8.Visible = true;
                star9.Visible = true;
                star10.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        conn3.Close();
```